# How to render js using haml rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm using haml and before i haven't any experience with haml. I'm fire ujs call whose code are below

```
  = link_to "this is the best",cast_vote_cast_votes_path(job_application.id),:id => job_application.id ,:remote => true ,:class => 'btn btn-primary best-button'
```

after this call is fire my function "cast_vote" execute and i have templete with name "cast_vote.js.erb". In which i just want to execute alert of js. But alert is not executing why?

i don't know. Any help please..

Comment: What does your `cast_vote.js.erb` file look like?

Comment: it is just one line                                                     alert("ok")

Comment: this is response of ajax call                                                         <div class='container container-width'>
      
           
       alert('ok')
    </div>

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your haml template:

```
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".best-button").click(function() {
       alert("ok");
    });
  });
```

Comment: This will show the alert, but not as a response to the ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the success callback for the remote ajax request to handle the response.  Add this script to your haml file:

```
$('.best-button')
  .bind('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr){ 
    eval(data.response);
  });
```

And change your js.erb to return a json object in the form `{response: 'alert("ok")'}`.